# Eloquent relationship through intermediate table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following database structure in my project:

```
products table

images table

product_images table 
with image_id, product_id, sort_order, main
```

where "main" flag indicates if it's the products main image.
Is there any way to have an eloquent function to get the main image of the product without having to call `Product::with(['images.image'])` ?
Like:

```
public function mainImage() {
  return $this->belongsToThrough(Image::class, ProductImages::class ,...)->where('main', true);
}
```

I tried hasOneThrough function but it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: In your product model,

public function images() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class);
}

e.g. To retrieve the main image,

$mainImage = Product::find(1)->images()->where('main', true)->get();

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function image() {
  return $this->belongsToOne(Image::class, ProductImages::class ,...)->where('main', true);
}
```

Create this function in the Product Model

and call it like `Product::with('image')`

Comment: belongsToOne doesn't exist in Laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve with creating a BelongsToOne Relation (as I needed a Relation instance to return). It might be useful for other developers too.

```
class BelongsToOne extends BelongsToMany {

    public function getResults() {
        $result = parent::getResults();
        return $result ? $result->first() : null;
    }
}
```

and extended the core Model class with

```
public function belongsToOne($related, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null, $relatedPivotKey = null,
                                 $parentKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null) {
        if (is_null($relation)) {
            $relation = $this->guessBelongsToManyRelation();
        }

        $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);

        $foreignPivotKey = $foreignPivotKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $relatedPivotKey = $relatedPivotKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();

        if (is_null($table)) {
            $table = $this->joiningTable($related, $instance);
        }

        return $this->newBelongsToOne(
            $instance->newQuery(), $this, $table, $foreignPivotKey,
            $relatedPivotKey, $parentKey ?: $this->getKeyName(),
            $relatedKey ?: $instance->getKeyName(), $relation
        )->limit(1);
    }

    protected function newBelongsToOne(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query, Model $parent, $table, $foreignPivotKey, $relatedPivotKey,
                                        $parentKey, $relatedKey, $relationName = null) {
        return new BelongsToOne($query, $parent, $table, $foreignPivotKey, $relatedPivotKey, $parentKey, $relatedKey, $relationName);
    }
```

I might look hacky but it works fine with eager loading too.